# scp with zsh : no matches found

Tags: zsh, scp

when I try scp over zsh, I get

```
scp hostA:Descargas/debian-6.0.4-* user@192.168.1.154:Escritorio/Software/
zsh: no matches found: hostA:Descargas/debian-6.0.4-*
```

the same command work in bash

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Escape your wildcard :

```
scp hostA:Descargas/debian-6.0.4-\*
```

Comment: I got the same error when trying to run a ruby resque worker with the `QUEUE=*` option. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Thanks for solution... This seems like an example of zsh being too smart for its own good...

Comment: Worked for me as well. Weird though!

Comment: \ does the trick on macos

Answer (score 37):

or add this to your `.zshrc`

```
alias scp='noglob scp'
```

Comment: It was so annoying to escape brackets when using ipv6, this helped.

Comment: not it says: `*: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 12):

Too late for the party, but..

You can escape the string with quotes too

```
scp "hostA:Descargas/debian-6.0.4-*" "user@192.168.1.154:Escritorio/Software/"
```

Answer (score 5):

Unset the `NOMATCH` option so that zsh leaves the text alone instead of complaining about a glob failure.

Comment: Hi, how to unset that? in `.zshrc` ?

Answer (score 5):

[This post](http://traviscj.com/tricks/?p=8) has a nice solution to this by using the url-quote-magic plugin to automatically escape globs in scp commands. To enable it, add the following to your `~/.zshrc`:

```
# Automatically quote globs in URL and remote references
__remote_commands=(scp rsync)
autoload -U url-quote-magic
zle -N self-insert url-quote-magic
zstyle -e :urlglobber url-other-schema '[[ $__remote_commands[(i)$words[1]] -le ${#__remote_commands} ]] && reply=("*") || reply=(http https ftp)'
```

When you type a glob character (like `*`) as part of a remote path in an scp or rsync command, zsh will automatically add a blackslash in front, like this:

```
scp hostA:Descargas/debian-6.0.4-\* user@192.168.1.154:Escritorio/Software/
```

Comment: This is a nasty but nice trick.

Comment: post url seems dead.

Answer (score 1):

I used to alias no "noglob scp" in my MacOS but with some updates I had always to type \scp at the beginning of the command so wildcards were accepted.

Changed to *alias scp="\noglob scp"* and it all work, with or without wildcards on command line.