# Prevent zsh from trying to expand everything

Tags: command-line, zsh

Recently switched from bash, I noticed that `zsh` will try to expand every command or argument that looks like it has wildcards in it. So the following lines won't work any more:

```
git diff master{,^^}
zsh: no matches found: master^^

scp remote:~/*.txt .
zsh: no matches found: remote:~/*.txt
```

The only way to make the above commands work is to quote the arguments, which is quite annoying.

**Q:** How do I configure `zsh` to still try to expand wildcards, but if there are no matches, just pass on the argument as-is?

**EDIT:** Possibly related: [scp with zsh : no matches found](https://superuser.com/q/420525)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is an *intended* feature of zsh. when using ***any*** shell, it is considered best practice to quote any character that is considered a meta character to the shell. `^` is a pattern used to negate a string when the option `extendedglob` is set. `*` is a pattern used to match zero or more characters.

You can stop it by disabling the option `nomatch`. But by doing so, your unquoted patterns make your statements volatile, depending on what files may be present in the current working directory. You shouldn't do that.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't, but it is quite tempting to do so. I used to think that I shouldn't have lots of aliases either. But in the end, all that matters is how long it takes for me to type in a command on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

For `scp`, see https://superuser.com/a/431568

For `git`, use `~` instead of `^`.